# While loop stops after 1 iteration [BASH]

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I have to read out a CSV file using bash. 
But my loop quits after 1 iteration.

Code:

```
function readCSVFile () {
input="bitbucket-repositories.csv";
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
while read repo tool folder;
do
  cd websites || exit
  cloneRepo $repo
  checkRepo
  cd ../ || exit 0
  checkTool  -> calls another script (../script.bash) -> no ssh
  countCSVLines
done < $input
IFS=$OLDIFS

}
```

Comment: try to replace your exit by `echo value`. Maybe you're exiting for some reason.

Comment: The whole thing runs, so that's not the problem I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which of the custom commands read from stdin? One of them is consuming the rest of the input file.

Try using a different file descriptor for the while read loop:

```
while read -r -u3 repo tool folder; do ... done 3< "$input"
```

Comment: Got a bit of progression with this one!
But what exactly does "-u3" do?

Comment: that reads from file descriptor 3 instead of the default 0 (stdin). At an interactive bash prompt, enter `help read`